# Is the use of a former hotel site as asylum seekers’ accommodation exempt from public disclosure under FOIA or EIR?

Tags: united-kingdom, environmental, freedom-of-information, environmental-information

Invariably when hotels are taken over by the authorities for asylum seekers' accommodation, they are staffed by zealously secretive security guards who refuse to answer basic questions about why, despite the hotel branding sign on the front of the building, the hotel is not accepting guests.

Yet the Freedom of Information Act and the Environmental Information Regulations require disclosure of such information of the use of premises by public bodies, and furthermore, the environmental information regulations (EIR) allow for environmental information requests to be made orally.

Are these zealously and  secretive security guards who become promptly combative in response to the most courteous of simple, benign and candid of basic questions, breaching an obligation to accept these requests for information under the EIR, if not to respond to the requests themselves?

While their stubborn and combative refusals to indulge basic and entirely respectful environmental queries from members of the public may or may not be lawful, they are obviously futile as right behind the zealous security guards are usually walls fully plastered in posters with information for asylum seekers about resources available to help them, the operation’s epidermis fully showing and exposed.

Comment: Reads more as a rant about encounters with uninformative security guards than as a  question about the law. What is the actual question that you want answered? The question in the headline?

Comment: From the official EIR webpage: "members of the public are entitled to request environmental information from public authorities." That would be your local council and not the security guards.

Comment: "basic and entirely respectful environmental queries": a question about why a hotel isn't accepting guests, from someone who can plainly see "walls fully plastered in posters with information for asylum seekers" and who knows that the hotel has been "taken over by the authorities for asylum seekers' accommodation" may or may not be "basic and entirely respectful," but it is certainly disingenuous.

Comment: @phoog you are entirely wrong in your assumptions and perhaps I will explain why once I’ve had some caffeine.

Answer (score 4):

The question is about the [Environmental Information Regulations 2004](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2004/3391/contents), a UK statutory instrument implementing [Directive 2003/4/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/ALL/?uri=CELEX%3A32003L0004), itself made for EU compliance with the Aarhus Convention of 1998. The thrust of the Regulations is that "a public authority that holds environmental information shall make it available on request" (regulation 5(1)). We must consider whether:

1. The presence or otherwise of asylum seekers in the hotel is "environmental information".
2. A private security guard at the location is part of "a public authority".

If these conditions are met then the oral request might be in scope of the Regulations. However, if the requestor is unsatisfied with the security guard's response, then their recourse (under Part IV of the [Freedom of Information Act 2000](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/36/contents), which applies here because of regulation 18) is first to exhaust  the internal complaints procedure of the public authority, before being able to apply to the Information Commissioner and so forth. The IC will disregard an application that says "I asked a security guard and he told me to go away" because the requestor has not yet shown that they have taken the request through proper channels - in particular, seeking out somebody whose actual job is to respond to this sort of request. There is no civil right of action outside of this procedure (FOIA section 56).

There is also a duty to "provide advice and assistance, so far as it would be reasonable to expect the authority to do so, to applicants and prospective applicants" (regulation 9). Once again the load-bearing word "reasonable" comes into play. I do not think it is reasonable to expect a security guard to be versed in environmental law or even to know in any detail how their organization wants EIR requests to be made. Even if the duty did apply, the only enforcement mechanism is what I described in the paragraph above, which naturally involves figuring out a more appropriate person to contact in any case.

In the remainder of this answer, which is strictly optional, I will say why I think a privately-contracted security guard at a hotel is not part of a public authority, and why the immigration status of people in the building is not "environmental information".

---

For Q2 above, a private company can potentially be a public authority for EIR purposes. The paradigmatic example is a water company, which is not part of government but is still providing a public service of environmental importance. In [*Fish Legal and Shirley* [2013] EUECJ C-279/12](https://www.bailii.org/eu/cases/EUECJ/2013/C27912.html) the Grand Chamber put forward the tests of whether the company has special powers in law relating to its public functions (e.g. "the right to impose temporary hosepipe bans"), and the extent of its autonomy from governmental control. Also relevant to Q1 is whether the information being requested is "environmental".

It seems to me that a company which is simply fulfilling a government contract, to carry out services of the kind it would do for any counterparty, is not a public authority. A hotel might rent out its rooms to anybody. A security company can provide people to stand around outside any building. Although the latter kind of company must be licensed by the Security Industry Authority, that does not mean it has the kind of special status referred to in *Fish Legal*. (If the security company is subcontracted by the hotel rather than by the Home Office directly, then the link is even more tenuous.) The correct authority for an EIR request would presumably be the Home Office, which is a central government department and therefore in scope of the Regulations automatically, or the appropriate local government body who might know about the hotel's current use.

But now, although for Q1 the term "environmental information" is to be construed broadly, it's also true that information does not become "environmental" just because an activity takes place in the environment where we all live. Article 2 of the Directive centres this concern on

> the state of the elements of the environment, such as air and atmosphere, water, soil, land, landscape and natural sites including wetlands, coastal and marine areas, biological diversity and its components, including genetically modified organisms, and the interaction among these elements

It can cover "the state of human health and safety" as it is affected by environmental conditions, or activities likely to affect "substances, energy, noise, radiation or waste, including radioactive waste, emissions, discharges and other releases into the environment".  Energy usage or waste in relation to a government building would be in scope, which is certainly connected to how many people are in it. But the immigration status of those people is not obviously a factor. A public authority could plausibly refuse to provide this information on that basis.

Alternatively, the public authority could decide that this *is* environmental information, but that it is not in the public interest to disclose it (regulation 12). That has been the case for previous FOIA requests relating to the use of hotels to house asylum seekers, where the Home Office has refused to provide detailed information. Several such instances can be seen on https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/ where the official response has invariably been to rely on FOIA s.38(1)(b),

> Information is exempt information if its disclosure under this Act would, or would be likely to, endanger the safety of any individual.

While the exemption regime of EIR is different, it is plausible that the public interest test would fall in the same way, if it came to that point. A minister, such as the Home Secretary, is also able to certify their decision conclusively (regulation 15) which limits the availability of judicial remedies.